# Is there an upper bound for fill-ins for indefinite triangular factorization?

Tags: sparse-matrix, matrix-factorization

For $A=LU$, or $A=LDL^T$ factorization, bandwidth is preserved when there is no pivoting. This is true even for indefinite A, see [question](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/16310/is-the-bandwidth-of-indefinite-a-equal-to-its-factor-l-in-ldlt). However, when there is pivoting band structure is destroyed, so fill-ins can occur outside the band. I am curious if there is any pivoting that can still preserve sparsity for the factors within some bounds.

Answer (score 2):

The commonly-used partial pivoting strategy
(selecting the pivot as the maximum coefficient
in the current column) can be used for band matrices.
If the lower bandwidth of the original matrix A is defined
as kl and the upper bandwidth as ku, the factors L and U
will have bandwidths kl+1 and ku+kl, respectively.
This result is shown in section 4.3.3 of [Matrix Computations](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0801854148), by Golub and
Van Loan.

This method is implemented in Lapack routine dgbtrf. The details of
the implementation are discussed here:
http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn21.pdf